# Screen Resolution on Mac Os High Sierra

Tags: virtual-machine, resolution

after i installed Mac OS x high sierra on Virtualbox
the resolution is 1024 x 768 but my host is 1366 x 768

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

i already use many method e.g.

**using com.apple.Boot.plist configuration
but i cannot change the file

using V Box Manage method**

but nothing can solve my problem

i hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

try this command on you console as admin and make sure to turn off your virtualbox.

> VBoxManage setextradata "Sierra" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1366x768

it worked for me